# Solving ODE $yy'=2x^3$ with $y(1)=3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck solving $yy'=2x^3$ with $y(1)=3$

I know that I'm looking to get the equation into the form of: $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ and then find the integrating factor $e^{\int(P(x)dx}$, but then how do I find my $P(x)$ in this case? And what do I do after with the initial condition?

Comment: You do not need an integrating factor ... it is variable seprable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$yy'=2x^3$$
$$\frac{1}{2} (y^2)'=2x^3$$
Simply integrate 
$$\frac{1}{2} y^2=\frac 12x^4+K$$
$$ y^2=x^4+K$$
$$y(1)^2=x^4+K \implies K=9-1=8$$
$$ y^2=x^4+8$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
y dy = 2 x^3 dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2 = x^4+K.
\end{eqnarray*}
$y(1)=3$ gives $K=8$.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still a bit lost. What do I do with my initial condition then? $y(1)=3$? I have a ton of these in my textbook and am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation

$$yy'=2x^3$$ is separable.

Integrate both sides and you get $$ \frac {y^2}{2} = \frac {x^4}{2}+c $$

Solve for $y,$ and with initial value $ y(1)=3,$ we get $$ y=\sqrt {x^4+8}$$

Comment: $$y=\pm\sqrt {x^4+8}$$

Comment: The negative is not acceptable because, y(1)=3 .

Comment: Oh sorry forgot that one